# How to get data from Mysql database for discord.js bot?

Tags: mysql, discord, discord.js

I have code of welcome system, where i save data of guild and get this data if memeber join. But i have a problem with get data from db, how i can fix it?

screenshot from database: https://imgur.com/a/N4q8d7b

but when I go to the server the line just skips and does not perform any actions in it

```
run()
async function run() {
    const db = await database.connect({ // creates a database connection
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '3306', // the default is 3306
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root123',
        database: 'database1',
        charset: 'utf8mb4'
    });


        client.on(Events.GuildMemberAdd, async (member) => {
            console.log(`User ${member.user.username} (${member.id}) join guild and add to database`)
            db.query(`SELECT welcomeChannel FROM welcomes WHERE "guildId" = '${member.guild.id}';`, function(result){
                console.log(`Result:${result}`)
            })
        
                console.log("1")
  
                const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setDescription(`Пользователь ${member} присоединился к серверу!`)
                //.setColor(embedcolor)
                //const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(Channelid)
                //channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
        })
};
  module.exports = {run}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I fully understand what you are saying, but I do have a feeling.

`db.query` returns 3 objects. These are, in order:

1. Error, when you have one
2. An array with the results
3. *Fields containing extra meta data about the results, if available (not really needed in your case)*

In the way you are doing it, it would look like this:

```js
db.query(`YOUR QUERY`, function (error, results) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results);
});
```

You had `results` in the first spot, where there error will be when there is one, which is why you weren't getting any results back.

You can read more in the docs [here](https://sidorares.github.io/node-mysql2/docs#first-query), click "Callback" to see the method you are using.